# No puedo consumir los datos de mi JSON con api

Tags: javascript, html, json

no estoy pudiendo consumir los siguientes datos que tengo en archivo data.json:

```
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nombre": "Correas Trapeciales Clásicas",
      "precio": 1500,
      "img": "../assets/img/clasicas.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "nombre": "Correas Trapeciales Dentadas",
      "precio": 500,
      "img": "../assets/img/dentadas.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "nombre": "Correas Automotor",
      "precio": 1000,
      "img": "../assets/img/automotor.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "nombre": "Correas Trapeciales Estrechas",
      "precio": 2000,
      "img": "../assets/img/estrechas.jpg"
    }
  ]
```

Para mostrarlo en mi HTML, en appi.js escribo:

```
let listado = document.getElementById("listado")
fetch("/data.json")
  .then((res)=>res.json())
  .then((data)=>{
    data.forEach((post,index)=>{
      const card = document.createElement("div")
      card.classList.add("card", "col-sm-12", "col-lg-3", "m-2");
      card.innerHTML=`
      <img class="card-img-top" src="${post.img}" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">${post.nombre}</h4>
        <p class="card-text">$ ${post.precio}</p>
        <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="agregarAlCarrito(${index})" >Agregar al Carrito</a>
      </div>
      `
      listado.append(card);
    })
  })
```

Se muestra perfecto y andan todas la funciones perfectamente, hasta que saco de mi app.js mi array de objetos que había creado antes de consumirlos por api y ahí dejan de funcionar las funciones de agregar carrito, mostrarlo y demás.

Comment: Qué significa "dejan de funcionar las funciones"? Cuál es el error que estás teniendo? Por favor agrégalo como texto en tu pregunta. Puedes hacer click en [edit]

Answer (score 0):

tal vez querías obtener los datos del producto al dar click en agregar al Carrito

```js
[
    {
      "id": 1,
      "nombre": "Correas Trapeciales Clásicas",
      "precio": 1500,
      "img": "../assets/img/clasicas.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "nombre": "Correas Trapeciales Dentadas",
      "precio": 500,
      "img": "../assets/img/dentadas.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "nombre": "Correas Automotor",
      "precio": 1000,
      "img": "../assets/img/automotor.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "nombre": "Correas Trapeciales Estrechas",
      "precio": 2000,
      "img": "../assets/img/estrechas.jpg"
    }
  ]



let listado = document.getElementById("listado")
let datos =[];
fetch("/data.json")
  .then((res)=>res.json())
  .then((data)=>{
    datos = data;
    data.forEach((post,index)=>{
      const card = document.createElement("div")
      card.classList.add("card", "col-sm-12", "col-lg-3", "m-2");
      card.innerHTML=`
      <img class="card-img-top" src="${post.img}" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h4 class="card-title">${post.nombre}</h4>
        <p class="card-text">$ ${post.precio}</p>
        <a href="#!" class="btn btn-primary" onClick="agregarAlCarrito(${index})" >Agregar al Carrito</a>
      </div>
      `
      listado.append(card);
    })
  })


  function agregarAlCarrito(row){
    console.log(datos[row])
   
  }
```

```html
<div class="card-body" id="listado">

    </div>
```